# Display different content depending on screen size and layout in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an android app which has 2 layouts, one for phones and one for tablets.

I have the two layouts made, but I'm having difficulty populating them with content. The phone layout (res/layout) consists of 1 list view which is populated from a database.

The tablet layout (res/layout-large) has 5 separate listviews which all need to be populated.

Basically I need some way of doing this:

```
if(screensize != large) {
  populateSingleListView();
}
else {
  populateMultipleListViews();
}
```

I tried using the following code to do it but it doesn't seem to detect the screen size within the emulator

```
(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
```

any ideas for a solution?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void populateList() {
    ListView list1 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list1);
    ListView list2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list2);

    if(list1 != null) {
        // Do sth
    }

    if(list2 != null) {
        // Sth else
    }
 }
```

So in small screen, you have list1 populate and big screen you have both populated.

Comment: You are welcome. If it works then click to accept as answer for future reference.

Comment: Hmm think the problem is relating to my emulator, for some reason it's not loading the resources from layout-large =[ EDIT: just fixed my avd and this seems to be working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using fragments (and a class to create each) for each list view.

The phone layout will have a single one, and you can set up the tablet layout to contain all of them.

If you define the class that populates the fragment in the xml then you don't have to worry about choosing, it will be done for you by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

try to detect it using display height & width

```
DisplayMetrics metrix = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrix);
displayHeigh = metrix.heightPixels;
displayWidth = metrix.widthPixels;

if(displayHeigh > displayWidth){ // or something else
    // for phone
}else{
    // for tablet
}
```